# java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused error while building on Travis

Tags: java, spring, testing, travis-ci

I am trying to build my spring boot project on Travis. I have test cases and while running these cases while building project on Travis I get this error. What the exactly problem is?

My test is here:

```
    private static final String API_ROOT = "http://localhost:8080/api/v1.0/notes";

    @Test
    public void whenGetAllNotes_thenOK() {
        
        final Response response = RestAssured.get(API_ROOT);
        assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK.value(), response.getStatusCode());
    }
```

Error log is here:

```
[ERROR] Tests run: 7, Failures: 0, Errors: 7, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.687 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.takeanote.note.NoteAPITest
[ERROR] whenDeleteCreatedNote_thenOk  Time elapsed: 1.503 s  <<< ERROR!
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at com.takeanote.note.NoteAPITest.createNoteAsUri(NoteAPITest.java:126)
```

Comment: Nothing is listening on localhost:8080 hence: `Connection refused` or there's a firewall issue.

Comment: It's also what I guess but what should I do?

Comment: Check why that api is not running on your PC.

Comment: I do not get any build&test error locally, it run successfully on my PC actually.

Comment: Well obviously ... you must have some service running on localhost:8080 **on your PC**.  But the service is not running **on the Travis host**.  (I assume you know that "localhost" is a loopback address.  It connects to "this" host ... wherever your code happens to be running.)

Comment: @StephenC you are right. I just add `-Dmaven.test.skip=true` into my .travis.yml file, and it built successfully, thanks for your comments.